# How to modify the CSS of the Google Hangouts extension window in Chrome (e.g. TamperMonkey)

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extensions, google-hangouts, css

I'm trying to remove the SMS badge from the avatar icon in my Google Hangouts conversation list. I can open the Developer Tools and make the change in the DOM, but I want an automated way to do it.

I have TamperMonkey installed, and I have a CSS declaration that works (.Dkouue {display:none}), but I can't get it to apply no matter which @match declarations I try.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different extension. On Chrome, using the [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) extension did not work for me. However, [Osprey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/osprey/ekjapccimkannnfgcnnoajhfdglobgak) amd [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en) (with the exact same code) did. *(The latter two are in fact just forks of Stylish — created because of privacy concerns related to [Stylish now being part of an analytics company](https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/53233/announcement-to-the-community) — but somehow they work whereas the original does not.)*

The code I used for the style is the same as yours:

```
.Dkouue {
    display: none;
}
```